# how to find the position of last occurrence of element in sequence with Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to find the position of the last occurence of an element in a sequence. Testing some solutions I came up with,

```
user> (def numbers (repeatedly 100 #(rand-int 100)))
#'user/numbers

user> (time ((zipmap numbers (range)) 22))
"Elapsed time: 0.865193 msecs"
90

user> (time (last (keep-indexed #(if (= 22 %2) %1) numbers)))
"Elapsed time: 1.600483 msecs"
90
```

Is there a more concise built-in that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lastIndexOf` after you cast the object to the correct type:

```
(.lastIndexOf numbers (int 22))
```

The method is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Yes, but note `.lastIndexOf` will actually work on the `LazySeq` directly, so long as you cast the element you are looking for the right type: `(.lastIndexOf numbers (int 22))`. The literal `22` will be considered a `long` otherwise and not be found even if `22` randomly did appear in the list.

Comment: @A.Webb Thanks, I will update my answer. I was wondering why it didn't work on `LazySeq`s directly but didn't find the reason.